# Saving the state of an activity to a name/or file

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, save

so i am creating a save system for my aplication, where each item in my recycler view in my (Mainactivity1), opens the same activity(MainActivity2). but i then want some way so that when i click on a button in (Mainactivity2) it saves the state of the activity(MainActivity2), but to a new name, so that i can load the activity from(MainActivity1). How is that done? in theory?
I just want to know how to save the instance of an activity to a name, loading the activity will be my headache.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to save an object. Then Java Serialization could help you

To Write Object

```
File fileToSaveObject=new File("path");
Object objectToSave=new Object();

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileToSaveObject);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

out.writeObject(objectToSave); // It will save 'objectToSave' in given file

out.close();
fileOut.close();
```

To Read Object

```
File fileToReadObject=new File("path");
Object objectToRead;

FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileToReadObject);
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

objectToRead= (Object) in.readObject();  // It will return you the saved object

in.close();
fileIn.close();
```

Comment: That might be a solution, so I can use that command to save an activity to a specified path? :)

Comment: I am not so familier with android programming, activity is a class or object of class?? If Yes then you can save that to specified path

Comment: it is a class :)

Comment: So you can save object of activity in file on a specified path, and retrieve the same object later